# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist, getting in every third hit to database

Tags: java, database, oracle, exception, oracle11g

i am working in a java project, where we are using oracle as a database and we have two schema, for every schema we are creating saprate connections in connection pool.

its working fine if we hit max 2 request at a time from the client for the data from a table but at every third time its getting `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` exception.

i want to understand why its happening and what would be the possible the reason? Please help me.

**Full Stacktrace:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:330)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:742)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:212)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:795)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1030)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:835)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3284)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3328)
    at DLRecordSetSQL.DLRecordSetSQL.setRecordCount(DLRecordSetSQL.java:3622)
    at DLRecordSetSQL.DLRecordSetSQL.open(DLRecordSetSQL.java:3124)
    at DLRecordSetSQL.DLRecordSetSQL.open(DLRecordSetSQL.java:3207)
    at com.utility.queryManager.util.MetadataManager.init(MetadataManager.java:79)
    at com.utility.queryManager.util.MetadataManager.<init>(MetadataManager.java:65)
    at com.utility.queryManager.processor.UtilityManagerRequestProcessor.selectCommandRequestProcessor(UtilityManagerRequestProcessor.java:187)
    at com.utility.queryManager.processor.UtilityManagerRequestProcessor.UtilityRequestProcessor(UtilityManagerRequestProcessor.java:77)
    at com.utility.queryManager.servlet.UtilityManagerServlet.doPost(UtilityManagerServlet.java:36)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: can you give more details, scripts ?

Comment: Maybe your connections get mixed up in the connection pool, and you are accessing the wrong schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your db is being run out of available connections.

You can set initial pool size 5. as it is default to 0.

For more, you can go through this tutorial: [Setting Connection Pool Properties in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm)

As [Avi stated](https://community.oracle.com/message/1150721#1150721) the issue as below

> Oracle database connections are not multi-threaded. If two or more
>   threads simultaneously try to access the same connection, one of them
>   will block until the other one finishes interacting with the
>   connection.
>
> So I guess you should try to verify whether your code exhibits this
>   behaviour trying to access the same database connection from multiple
>   threads at the same time.